# Making a CMD for pyqt GUI app

Tags: python

I have been searching around on how to embed a CMD into a pyqt gui. I found the CMD module but it does not work with pyqt even when i did multithreading and processing. Does anyone have an idea or an example on how to?

Comment: "But it doest not work with pyqt even when I did multithreading ..." -- What doesn't work?  More details about why this approach failed would be useful.

Comment: I assume you mean embedding a terminal? are you talking about a DOS terminal? a linux terminal? a python terminal?

Comment: A console of my own, where I define functions, to controll my GUI to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

pycrust/pyshell are good python embedded terminals

if you just need the standard DOS cmd you could just do

```
os.system("cmd")
```

not sure if you want a linux terminal

Comment: I want a custom console/termianl, where I define functions, to controll my GUI to a certain extent

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have this right, because the question was somewhat vague, but I'll try. Here is my idea. Create a text edit widget in your pyqt gui. Then create an instance of cmd.Cmd and pass the text edit widget's file object as the first and second arguments (stdout and stdin.) This might not work, because I don't know if a text edit widget can act as a file object. Here's how it would look:

```
c = cmd.Cmd(stdin = widget, stdout = widget)
```

Tell me if I made a mistake, because I am not 100% sure.